# Adding Scala to the PATH in zsh

Tags: linux, zsh, path, elementaryos

I've been at this for a while and I think I'm starting to go crazy

I have downloaded Scala to `~/bin` for easy access on my Elementary machine; but I seem to have some difficulty adding it to the `PATH`.

On my Macbook I simply added the following to `.profile` and everything just worked:

```
SCALA_HOME=~/bin/scala-2.11.7
PATH=$PATH:SCALA_HOME/bin
```

On my Elementary box however, I've tried putting the same code in both `.profile` and `.zshrc`, and it still doesn't doesn't correctly display `/Users/coffee/bin/scala-2.11.7/bin/scala` when writing `which scala`.

So what am I doing wrong here, and how do I get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `$` sign in order to make the shell evaluate the `SCALA_HOME` variable:

```
SCALA_HOME=~/bin/scala-2.11.7
PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
# Here ----^
```

Comment: in which file? Also making that change in the `.zshrx` did nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a different Scala provided by your distribution, you may need to both add the `$` as per Mureinik's answer, and make sure that your path entry **comes before the `$PATH`**:

```
export SCALA_HOME=~/bin/scala-2.11.7
export PATH=$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

These should be set in `~/.zshenv` and probably need to have "export" added, otherwise programs run from zsh will not see it.